# Django html input UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, django

My Django version is 1.5a1 and Python version: 3.2.3

I get an

```
UnicodeEncodeError 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe3' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

with the html fragment:

```
<input name="test" value="S&#227;o Paulo" type="submit" />
```

My html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type">
```

I can't find why Django converts html input to ascii before creating an instance of django.http.HttpRequest and giving it to my python view.

Comment: Any reason to run 1.5a1 (alpha!) when 1.5.1 is now the latest (stable) version? And also note that Python 3 support is still experimental in 1.5.x

Comment: Django is not doing that, your code is somewhere. However since you have failed to show any of the code that is producing that fragment, we are unable to guess where.

Comment: Hi,


I updated Django to version 1.5.1 and now everything is OK.


Thank you gertvdijk.